# Smart admin with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, nav

I am using angularjs from 2 months but never comes to problem like this, so thought of sharing with you people and getting some good suggestion on that. Here I am trying to apply ul/nav-group element dynamic values. Everything is working fine means, if I see developer tools on browser it gets value and everything, but not the +/- sign. I search on google its saying that it loads after DOM creation so it is not showing that. But no buddy tells the solution for that. 
Consider my code:

```
<nav:group ng-repeat="parentChild in parentChildList" title="{{parentChild.filterText}}">
    <nav:item data-view="/ui/icons/fa" ng-repeat="childs in parentChild.childList" data-icon="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-plane" title="{{childs.filterText}}" />
</nav:group>
```

The value for particular fields are straight forward means its simple list.How the directive can solve this problem.
Appreciate any suggestions . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ng-cloak directive on the body tag of your app to prevent loading the element until angular has finished loading.

Your body tag would look like this:

```
<body ng-cloak>
...
</body>
```

You could also fix this by using promises in your services, that is definitely the best practice regardless, but ng-cloak is a quick and easy fix.

Hope that helps! If ng-cloak doesnt work for you post snippets of your controller and service and I will help you add promises.

Good Luck!
-Justin

Comment: Thanks for your response but ng-cloak does not works for me, inside services already I am using promises to get the json data.